# Internal only HTTP Cloud Function unreachable

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set up a HTTP Cloud Function that allows only internal traffic, as explained in [Google’s public docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#ingress_settings).

However, when I try to access the function from a GCE instance that does not have an external IP address it does not work, and gives me the following error:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2v00.png)

As you can see in the following screenshots, I have both the Function and the GCE instance in the same region:

[Functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT4cJ.png)

[GCE network interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yP5R.png)

This project only has **1** VPC network, which is the default one, and the source code for the Cloud Function is the default suggestion of the Console:

[Source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8wdN.png)

Strangely enough, if I give an external IP address to the GCE instance it works, so does it mean that the traffic is still going to the internet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a compute engine lacks an external IP, it can only send packets to other internal IP address destinations. You still have to connect to a set of external IP addresses used by Google APIs and services. This can be done by enabling Private Google Access on the subnet used by the VM/function

[image]

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access